# ImportError: No module named elementtree.SimpleXMLWriter

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xmlwriter

In my python code I am trying to display the output in a XML format.For this purpose I am using `XMLwriter`.

But it is showing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ponmani\Desktop\test.cgi", line 8, in <module>
    from elementtree.SimpleXMLWriter import XMLWriter
ImportError: No module named elementtree.SimpleXMLWriter
```

The line which causes the error is:

```
from elementtree.SimpleXMLWriter import XMLWriter
```

My entire python code is:

```
import os
import cgi
import MySQLdb
import cgitb
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from elementtree.SimpleXMLWriter import XMLWriter
import sys
import SecureDb
cgitb.enable()
print "Content-type: text/xml\n\n";
root=xml.start("root")
conn= MySQLdb.connect(host = SecureDb.host ,user =SecureDb.user ,passwd=SecureDb.password ,db=SecureDb.database)
cursor=conn.cursor()
xml=XMLWriter(sys.stdout)
cursor.execute("select * from register where Name='Subburaj'")
result=cursor.fetchall()
if(result!=()):    
    for colns in result:
         xml.start("Group")
         xml.element("Name","%s" %(colns[0]))
         xml.element("Mail","%s" %(colns[1]))
print result
xml.end()
xml.close(root)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: is the ``elementtree`` module installed in your environment?

Comment: you need to install [elementtree toolkit](http://effbot.org/zone/xml-writer.htm) i reckon.

Comment: which version of python are you using? this error indicates you have no elementtree installed. Which OS is this?

Comment: I am using windows vista(64 bit) ..python version is 2.7

Answer (score 3):

The `ElementTree` module as shipped with Python 2.5 and up does *not* include the `SimpleXMLWriter` module; the latter is entirely separate from the rest of the `ElementTree` functionality.

To generate XML, I personally use a templating language such as [Chameleon](http://chameleon.repoze.org/). You can also build the tree by using the ElementTree API itself and simply call `.write()` on the result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a wizard with XML, however, it looks like you either need to install [elementtree](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/elementtree/) (apparently SimpleXMLWriter [wasn't included in python2.5](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-August/068128.html) ... and maybe it's never been pulled into the standard library), or use the facilities in the standard library.

To me, it looks like something like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element('root')
#...

for colns in result:
     new_group = ET.SubElement(root,"Group")
     new_elem = ET.SubElement(new_group,"Name")
     new_elem.text = "%s" %(colns[0])
     #I suppose that:
     #ET.SubElement(new_group,"Name").text = str(colns[0])
     #would work too ...
     new_elem = ET.SubElement(new_group,"Mail")
     new_elem.text = "%s" %(colns[0])
```

You can then write this using `root.write()`.

[reference1](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents)

[reference2](https://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/tag/simplexmlwriter/)